# php str_replace casting integer to scientific number

Tags: php, numbers, scientific-notation

I do have issues with str_replace on my webserver casting intergers to scientific number notation.

```
$strContent = "Yesterday was ##yesterdayTimestamp##!";
$yesterDayTimestamp = floor((time() - (24 * 3600)) / (24 * 3600)) * 24 * 3600 * 1000 ;
$strContent = str_replace("##yesterdayTimestamp##", $yesterDayTimestamp, $strContent) ;

echo $strContent;

// expected output / result on local server
// "Yesterday was 1423612800000!"

// result on remote production server
// "Yesterday was 1.4236128E+12!"
```

Trying to solve the problem with `str()` or `format_number()` seem not to work

How can I prevent php from using the scientific notation in code?

I found a solution to the question by changing the php configuration e.g.: [PHP Scientific Notation Shortening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846525/php-scientific-notation-shortening).
However since I'm in an hosted environment this is not as easy.

Comment: And what is the question now? What output do you expect/want? (BTW: Your calculation seems to be a bit weird, you just multiple the timestamp with 1000?!)

Comment: You're on a 32bit PHP, and your calculated number great exceeds the max representable integer, which is 2**31 - 1. A float is the ONLY way your value can be represented.

Comment: Looks like you're using millisecond timestamps. PHP timestamps are in **SECONDS**, so you're coming out 1000x larger than you need to be. If you wanted a yesterday timestamp, why not just `time() - 86400`?

Comment: Consider the math formula as not related to the questions issue. Its just the way i need it. Dates in my db are stored as microseconds since I need it to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there are less than 14 significant digits, `printf(%f)` works fairly well:

```
$big = 1234567890123456;
echo $big, "\n";         # 1.2345678901235E+15
printf("%.0f\n", $big);  # 1234567890123456
```

If you need more, consider BCMath/GMP

Comment: thx georg, this is going into the right direction, however I need to replace it correctly into $strContent, thus I cannot use printf

Comment: @Manuel: you need a string, try `sprintf`.